# In the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition $M=D+N$, how obtaining $D$ and $N$ as polynomials in $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

The [Jordan-Chevalley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition) expresses a linear operator $M$ as
$$
M = D + N,
$$
where $D$ is semisimple (diagonalizable), $N$ is nilpotent and $DN=ND$. Although it is stated in many sources that $D$ and $N$ can be written as polynomials in $M$, I never see any *method* for obtaining such polynomials. I want to emphasize that I am not interested in a proof about the existence of these polynomials, but in a procedure for explicitly obtaining them *given* the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition.

Comment: If you already know $D$, $N$, expressing them as linear combination of $I,M,M^2,...,M^{n-1}$ is a simple Gaussian elimination problem.

Comment: That is not clear to me. Could you expand your comment into an explicit answer?

Comment: @Jobe: They mean that since you know $D$ and $N$ lie in the linear span of $I, M, M^2, \ldots, M^{n-1}$, just form a linear system and solve it to find particular linear combinations that actually result in $D$ and $N$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write $\chi_M(X)=\prod_{k=1}^s{(X-\lambda_k)^{\alpha_k}}$ (characteristic polynomial).

From among others Cayley-Hamilton, we know that $\bigoplus_{k=1}^s{\ker((M-\lambda_kI)^{\alpha_k})}=\mathbb{C}^n$ (for instance).

Let, for each $k$, $A_k$, $B_k$ be polynomials such that $A_k(X)(X-\lambda_k)^{\alpha_k}+B_k(X)\prod_{l \neq k}{(X-\lambda_l)^{\alpha_l}}=1$.

Let $P_k(X)=B_k(X)\prod_{l \neq k}{(X-\lambda_l)^{\alpha_l}}$.

Then, if $(M-\lambda_kI)^{\alpha_k}v=0$, then $P_k(M)v=v$. On the other hand, if $l \neq k$ and $(M-\lambda_lI)^{\alpha_l}v=0$, then $P_k(M)v=0$.

Then $D=\sum_k{\lambda_kP_k(M)}$.

Comment: I am having a hard time to fully understand your answer. One point: how can one compute $A_k(X)$ and $B_k(X)$? I have tried for some cases, but I could not. Is the relation between $A_k$ and $B_k$ a version of the Bézout's identity?

Comment: Yes. That’s Euclid algorithm for polynomials.

Comment: Ok. I will spend some additional time to completely understand your answer before accept it. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: I think coprime will give you a hint