# Polynomial to obtain the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Studing the Cartan's Criterion proof, I came across this previous statement:

> Given $A$ endomorphism of $V$ vector space over $K$ closed field in a certain basis, there exists a polynomial $Q(t)$ such that $Q(A)=D$, where $D$ is the diagonal part of the JCF of $A$.

By Cayley Hamilton theorem, I know $P(A)=0$, being $P$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$, but I don't know how to obtain this result, that seems to be easy as it is left as an exercise. Further it is said as well the existance of another polynomial $T(t)$ such that $T(D)=*D$, the conjugate of $D$, in this case we can use  Lagrange interpolation to prove it.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not trivial, but it is a  classical fact. See for instance the following question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111246/in-the-jordan-chevalley-decomposition-m-dn-how-obtaining-d-and-n-as-poly